# Who discards IP packet when TTL becomes 0

Tags: ip

If the TTL of a IP packet becomes 0, then who will discard the IP packet i.e., either router or host.

Comment: It's most likely a router will discard the packet. Depends on which piece of hardware the packet traverses when it reaches a TTL of 0.

Answer (score 5):

It's the router that discards it. From this [post](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=680824&seqNum=4) on CiscoPress:

Time To Live (TTL) is a well-known mechanism thanks to IP. In the IP header is a field of 8 bits that signifies the time that a packet still has before its life ends and is dropped. When an IP packet is sent, its TTL is usually 255 and is then decremented by 1 at each hop. If the TTL reaches 0, the packet is dropped. In such a case, the router that dropped the IP packet for which the TTL reached 0 sends an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) message type 11 and code 0 (time exceeded) to the originator of the IP packet.

Answer (score 3):

The router.

If the TTL is 0, the packet is discarded, and never reaches the host.

More information in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)